# Using a transformer with 400 volt rated primary side with a 120 volt line

Tags: current, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, switching

Is it possible to use a transformer rated for 360 to 400 volts on its primary side on a 120 volt line? Will it still perform adequately? And I would assume the turns ratios still apply?

This is the transformer in question: *[WE-LLCR Resonant Converter](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/445/760895751-270509.pdf)*.

Also, I understand that the saturation current is that which the inductance drops off; however, this datasheet says the I-sat is 4 amperes, but it's rated for 8 amperes output current. Why is this so?

I will be using this in an [SMPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply) at 100 kHz.

Comment: Are you sure that's the right kind of transformer for your project? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Yes i forgot to mention that I was using it in a 100khz switching mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the datasheet, it says Resonant Converter. The only resonant converters that I have worked on were to get high voltage outputs without feedback. I think there may not be any difference in the transformer construction and you can use it for the much more common PWM scheme SMPS.

The 4A saturation current spec is for the primary.

The transformer can function for 400V or below. One of the key spec here is the primary inductance -- 400uH, it determines the current rise for a given on time. Back of the envelope calculations: at 120VDC input, 0.5us on time (50% of the period of 100KHz), discontinuous current mode (flyback topology), the transformer can transfer no more than 45W. At 320VDC input, 320W. And these are assuming 100% efficiency.

SMPS can be fun, but be careful when dealing with 120V or greater. In the common flyback topology, the flyback voltage would add on top of that.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is - only if you want tiny output currents.

This is a transformer intended for DC-DC converter use. If you go to page 2 of the data sheet, you'll see that its' intended frequency is 70 to 120 kHz. That is, it's intended to operate 1000 times faster than line frequency. That's why you can get so much current out of a small transformer. To a first approximation, this says that its' output current at 60 Hz will be limited to about 1000 times less than the rating you've quoted. Plus, since it's intended to operate in a resonant configuration, I'm not certain you'd get even that.

You're looking at a very small transformer and thinking that maybe you can get 480 watts out of it, right? Sorry, but no. Not at line frequencies.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention that I was intending to use it in a switching power supply at 100khz.

Comment: @AndrewCragg That's kind of an important thing to forget. The power supply rail created from 120VAC will normally be 160 or 320 volts DC (the latter if a doubler is used).